# Solving the linear differential equation $x \sin x \frac{dy}{dx} + (\sin x + \cos x) y = \frac{e^x}{x}$, subject to the initial condition $y(-1/2)=0$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am studying and solving the exercises from the book [Linear Analysis](https://archive.org/details/AnIntroductionToLinearAnalysis) by the authors Kreider, Kuller, Ostberg and Perkins in my differential equations course. An exercise asks :

> Solve the linear first order differential equation
> $$x \sin x \space \frac{dy}{dx} + (\sin x + \ cos x)y=\frac{e^x}{x}$$
>
> subject to the initial condition $y(-1/2)=0$.

So, I tried finding an integrating factor and that's

$$\exp \left[\int \frac{dx}{x}+\int \frac{\cot x}{x}dx\right]$$

But, the second term doesn't appear to yield an antiderivative that can be expressed in terms of elementary functions. I tried using the product rule. Could you give me a hint, if I am missing something here, or tips to make some progress on this problem?

Bests,
Quasar.

Comment: WA says this here $$\left\{\left\{y(x)\to c_1 \exp \left(\int_1^x
   -\frac{K[1]+K[1] \cot (K[1])}{K[1]^2} \,
   dK[1]\right)+\exp \left(\int_1^x -\frac{K[1]+K[1]
   \cot (K[1])}{K[1]^2} \, dK[1]\right) \int_1^x
   \frac{\csc (K[2]) \exp \left(K[2]-\int_1^{K[2]}
   -\frac{K[1]+K[1] \cot (K[1])}{K[1]^2} \,
   dK[1]\right)}{K[2]^2} \, dK[2]\right\}\right\}$$

Comment: Are you sure about the equation ? Even removing the $x$ in front, it is a difficult problem.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici it's number 5, on page 124 of the file OP linked

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici OP provided a link. Regardless, the purpose of my comment was only to say that it was word for word the same problem from the book. The problem two rows up was only $2y'+3y=e^{-x}$, and errata for this book are nowhere to be found.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, yeah it doesn't seem very tractable to me. It could be a typo. But, there's no errata for the book. Thanks again guys.

Comment: @NinadMunshi  you sure its on page 124 ? I see no exercice with number 5

Comment: @Isham it's 124 of the file, not the page number of the book. The page number is 104 I think but I am not sure.

Comment: thank you @NinadMunshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an early comment, I was suspecting that removing the front $x$ would make the system workable. I was partly wrong.

Considering
$$\sin (x)\, y'+ (\sin (x)+\cos (x))\,y=\frac{e^x} x$$ first let $y=z\, e^x$ to make
$$\sin (x)\, z'+ (2 \sin (x)+\cos (x))\,y=\frac 1x$$ For the homogeneous equation, we get
$$z=C\, e^{-2 x} \csc (x)$$ Variation of parameters leads to 
$$C'=\frac {e^{2 x}} x=\frac {e^{2 x}} {2x}d(2x)\implies C=\text{Ei}(2 x)+K$$ where appears the exponential integral function (and this is non-trivial).

Back to $y$
$$y=e^{-x} \csc (x) \left(K+\text{Ei}(2 x)\right)$$ and using the condition
$$y=e^{-x}\,\csc (x)\,(\text{Ei}(2 x)-\text{Ei}(-1)) $$